# One box, multiple ports, multiple domains, ONE SSL cert

Tags: node.js, apache, ssl, https

I have about 5-6 node.js web apps all running off of different ports that proxy to two domains via apache. Can someone guide me on how I would set up SSL for this? Could I just buy one comprehensive multi-domain/wildcard SSL cert and import that into all of my different applications?

I just need to be pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

For any future lurkers, I recommend using [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/), and then having the node HTTPS servers pull from that one certificate on the local machine. I wrote an npm module called [iomicro](https://npmjs.com/package/iomicro) that, among other things, does this.